# List posts of custom post type under category name

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, frontpage

I want to display category name as a collapsible headers and inside the collapsible body I want to display post titles linking back to original post.

I am using custom post type 'University' and custom taxonomy 'country'. So far I managed to get custom taxonomies names as header but unable to get posts inside the custom taxonomy.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">   
<ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">

<?php
$args = array(
'post_type'              => array( 'university' ),
'post_status'            => array( 'publish' ),
'taxonomy'               => 'country',
'posts_per_page'         => '1',

);
// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

$categories = get_categories($args);

// The Loop
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    $query->the_post(); 
    // do something

    foreach ($categories as $category){ ?>

    <li class="home-list hoverable col m6 z-depth-1">
    <div class="collapsible-header"><h5><i class="material-icons teal-text">add_circle_outline</i>
        <?php
        //echo var_dump($category);         
        $cat_name = $category->name;
        $cat_count = $category->count;

        echo 'Medical Universities in '.$cat_name;
        //echo $category->count;
        echo '</h5></div>';?>

    <div class="collapsible-body"><span>
        <?php
         echo $cat_count;
            $custom_terms = get_terms('country');
            //echo var_dump($custom_terms);

        ?>

    </span></div>   
        <?php


    }
        ?>
    </li>


    <?php }
} else {
// no posts found
}

// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Thank you all for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this:

```
$categories = get_categories( 'country' );

foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
  $posts_array = get_posts ( array (
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'university',
    'tax_query' => array (
      array(
      'taxonomy' => 'country',
        'field' => 'term_id',
        'terms' => $category->term_id,
      )
    )
  ) );

  var_dump( $posts_array );
}
```

UPDATE:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">   
    <ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">

    <?php
    $categories = get_terms( 'country' );

    foreach ( $categories as $category ) : ?>

      <li class="home-list hoverable col m6 z-depth-1">

        <div class="collapsible-header">
          <h5>
            <i class="material-icons teal-text">add_circle_outline</i>
            <?php echo 'Medical Universities in ' . esc_html( $category->name ) . ' (' . $category->count . ')'; ?>
          </h5>
        </div>

        <div class="collapsible-body">

          <?php
          $posts_array = get_posts ( array (
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'post_type' => 'university',
            'tax_query' => array (
              array(
              'taxonomy' => 'country',
                'field' => 'term_id',
                'terms' => $category->term_id,
              )
            )
          ) );

          if ( $posts_array ) :

            foreach ( $posts_array as $university ) : ?>

              <h3><a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink( $university->ID ) ); ?>"></a></h3>

            <?php endforeach;

          else : ?>

            <p>No posts found</p>

          <?php endif; ?>

        </div>

      </li>

    <?php endforeach; ?>

    </ul>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Minh for time but I am getting : 
array (size=0)
  empty
I am using this code on front-page.php

Comment: Can you make sure you have posts under each categories? Can you show me a screenshot of your posts list from wp backend?

Comment: Hi Minh please check the screenshot here https://snag.gy/DsKJre.jpg I have 15 posts in 5 custom taxonomies

Comment: Can you check with `$categories = get_terms( 'country' );`?

Comment: Yes Im getting this result https://snag.gy/0YqU2B.jpg array (size=6) and can see all country created

Comment: also public 'count' => int 3 but unable to fetch these 3 posts from country 'georgia'

Comment: Ok please use the full code I just updated. It should works.